# Making Request from Database - Laravel & PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I am making a request from my database in function but then I get an error `trying to get property of non-object`. But nothing is wrong with my code for it to return the error

```
>>trying to get property of non-object.
```

**Controller**

```
 public function shopHook(Request $request)
    {
        $shop = $request->getContent();
        $shop = json_decode($shop, true);
        $shop_id = $shop['number'];
        $get_msg = ShopCancelled::where('name',Auth::user()->domain)->first();
    }
```

**Web Route**

```
Route::post('shop-cancel-webhook', 'AppController@shopHook');
```

Why could this be happening? The code seems to be breaking at

```
$get_msg = ShopCancelled::where('name',Auth::user()->domain)->first();
```

When making the request

Comment: Seems like `Auth::user()` is null. Is the authentication working properly?

Comment: check if the error happens when you access `domain`: `Auth::user()->domain`

Comment: try replacing Auth::user()->domain with some dummy string to see if error goes away.

Comment: If you are requesting it in API, auth session is not properly set. If I'm right, first of all you need to look up about api auth

Comment: @Phiter, okay so Auth::user() is null and when i hardcoded the domain in replace, it worked. But why is it null ?

Comment: Are you logged in? Are you Authenticated before you run the above api?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in this line:

```
$shop_id = $shop['number'];
```

try instead `$shop_id = $shop->number;`

Comment: If you have red the comments above, its all about auth. `Auth::user()` is returning null =))

Answer (score 0):

That error is because you are trying to access to a property inside an object that has not been instantiated or doesn't have that property.
Would be helpful if you can point out exactly the line where the error is presented.